# Rest Api for search by products, brands and more using single search input

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to Node and Mongodb.
I want to implement Search Rest api, with single param passing to api resulting to search in mongo collections checking the category, subCategory values and returning the related keyword matching object. just like flipkart search bar, with suggestion keywords, what should i follow to achieve this. i'm just having knowledge with basic CRUD operations that's all. Any suggestions or ref practices are helpful to me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can follow two approaches for the above implementation.

1) Basic approach. We can create a search collection which would have the following field like

```
Search
_id, name, description, type (brand, products, etc), type_id (brand_id, product_id), logo (It can be a brand logo, or product logo and etc).
```

On every product, brand, etc add we would create an entry in the search table.
Similarly, on deletion, we would remove that product or brand from the search table

We would have an end called http:///search/:string
Which would in response give result as

```
{
  data: [
    {
    _id: 507f1f77bcf86cd799439011,
    name: 'Clothing',
    description: "Sample description about clothing",
    type: 'brand',
    type_id: 675f1f77bcf86cd799439124,  // brand id reference,
    logo: "http://<domain_name>/logo/675f1f77bcf86cd799439124"
  },
  {
    _id: 5d3f1f77bcf86cd799439234,
    name: 'Monitor',
    description: "Sample description about Monitor",
    type: 'product',
    type_id: 5j5f1f77bcf86cd799439987,  // product id reference
    logo: "http://<domain_name>/logo/5j5f1f77bcf86cd799439987"

  }, {
    _id: 507f1f77bcf86cd799439333,
    name: "Mobile",
    description: "Sample description about Mobile",
    type: 'brand',
    type_id: 876f1f77bcf86cd799439444,  // brand id reference
    logo: "http://<domain_name>/logo/876f1f77bcf86cd799439444"

  }
```

]
 }

2) Sophisticated approach: Instead of using a search table you can go with the elastic search for a faster and robust approach

Answer (score 0):

you can use **mongodb text search** feature
or you can go with **elasatic** search as per your requirement.